# Is there any alternative BAPI/FM for BAPI_SALESORDER_SIMULATE to get the pricing data when we provide materials for salesorder create?

Tags: simulation, sap-erp, bapi, alternate

Say we create sales order and provide a Material and it will give Pricing details....

Now requirement is we can use `BAPI_SALESORDER_SIMULATE` to provide inputs and it will return pricing data but thus takes lot of time when more materials are provided on selection screen.

So please let me know if there is any BAPI/FM?

I need an alternate logic/BAPI/FM.

Comment: `BAPI_SIMULATE` doesn't exist neither in SAP ECC nor in S/4HANA. Which SAP software is it?

Comment: I mean, BAPI_SALESORDER_SIMULATE,

Comment: I need to get pricing ( which includes frieght+tax+ etc)details when we create order,
when we use BAPI_SALESORDER_SIMULATE, it takes lot of time, so need an alternative

Comment: Thanks. No need to repeat yourself, please update the question if you feel that some details are missing. I still have a doubt about software, so I indicate [tag:sap-erp].